# url rewrite using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, sef

I have a number of url I would like to change using htaccess could someone kindly help me out with the code so i can create some sef, i have 50 other pages to change so just look at the right code to add to htaccess, i called my host useless, and developer is not sure, but google needs this so any help would be greatful!

Current url: http://www.website.com/job-search/simple-search/guest/jobsby_criteria/jobcateg/1-accountancy-jobs

New url: http://www.website.com/accountancyjobs

Comment: What are some other examples of old and new URLs?

Comment: i want to turn the current in to the new url

Comment: Yes I know but can you provide 1 more example of current/new URLs?

Comment: http://www.website.com/job-search/simple-search/guest/jobsby_criteria/jobcateg/51-agriculture-jobs this site has job categories listed on the index page so im looking for the reWrite rule for .htaccess can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.+?\d+-([^-]+)-(jobs)/?$ /$1$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: i have added the following and it has not worked?  and im not sure why it would work as it doesnt have a url to redirect to

Comment: i have a .htaccess ad a .htaccess.txt in the root the site is based on cms platform joomla 2.5, i placed the code at the bottom of .htaccess uploaded to the root still doesnt work?

Comment: Not bottom, it must be first rule just below `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: i have just tried that now im getting a 404 page not found? simply add the RewriteRule ^.+?\d+-([^-]+)-(jobs)/?$ /$1$2 [L,NC,R=302] is the correct?

Comment: its an internal 404 page error so it the page i created rather then a server side error